# Change Symfony public directory to fit website

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I want to create directory called 'app' in my public directory and make it root of my application instead of 'public' dir. What should I do except adding:

```
"extra": {
    "public-dir": "public/app/",
...
}
```

I got a vue app that should be placed in 'app' directory and a wordpress instance that will be placed in 'public' directory so when I enter www.mywebsite.com I get wordpress website, and when I enter www.mywebsite.com/app I got my symfony/vue app.
So far I edited my webpack.config.js with:

```
.setOutputPath("public/app/build/")
.setPublicPath("/build/")
```

And it think it works on dev env but in prod env when i hit www.mywebsite.com/app I got:

```
 <script src="/build/app.js"></script>
```

Which wrongly points to: www.mywebsite.com/build/app.js instead of www.mywebsite.com/app/build/app.js
But whenever I change webpack.config.js to:

```
.setOutputPath("public/app/build/")
.setPublicPath("/app/build/")
```

It works on production but not on dev env.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your problem description I'm assuming your application is accessed at `/` in your `dev` environment, but `/app` in your `prod` environment as explained. So you have to take that into account when calling `.setConfigPath()` by checking the environment you are running in your webpack config:

```
.setPublicPath(Encore.isProduction() ? '/app/build' : '/build')
```

Comment: Ok, thank you that worked for me. Could you also tell me why in my prod env symfony twig paths starts from www.website.com/asset/js/app.js intead of ww.website.com/app/asset/js/app.js? In twig i make import like:  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/asset/js/app.js') }}" />

Comment: @bad_programmer The `asset` function takes into account the `public-dir` setting and uses that as the root, so no `/app` because that *is* the root.

Comment: in composer.json i set public-dir to be public/app/. What does is the root of my app?

Comment: @bad_programmer On second thought, I'm not so sure about my previous statement. When a request comes in, symfony uses the `RequestContext` to determine the app root using the uri. Not so sure how does the `public-dir` setting factor into it. But the internal web server *does* use `public-dir` as the app root.